# Parse a list, check if it has elements from another list and print out these elements

Tags: python, list

I have a list populated from entries of a log; for sake of simplicity, something like

```
listlog = ["entry1:abcde", "entry2:abbds", "entry1:eorieo", "entry3:orieqor", "entry2:iroewiow"......]
```

This list can have an undefined number of `entry`, which may or may not be in sequence, since I run multiple operations in async fashion.

Then I have another list, which I use as reference to get only the list of entries; which may be like

```
list_template = ["entry1", "entry2", "entry3"]
```

I am trying to use the second list, to get sequences of entries, so I can isolate the single sequence, taking only the first instance found of each entry.

Since I am not dealing with numbers, I can't use `set`, so I did try with a loop inside a loop, comparing values in each list

This does not work, because it is possible that another entry may happen before what I am looking for (say, I want entry1, entry2, entry3, and the loop find entry1, but then find entry3, and since I compare every element of each list, it will be happy to find an element)

```
for item in listlog:
    entry, value = item.split(":")
    for reference_entry in list_template:
        if entry == reference_entry:
            print item
            break
```

I have to, in a nutshell, find a sequence as in the template list, while these items are not necessarily in order. I am trying to parse the list once, otherwise I could do a very expensive multi-pass for each element of the template list, until I find the first occurrence and bail out. I thought that doing the loop in the loop is more efficient, since my reference list is always smaller than the log list, which is usually few elements.

How would you approach this problem, in the most efficient and pythonic way? All that I can think of, is multiple passes on the log list

Comment: `set` works with strings as well

Comment: your inner `for` loop can be rewritten as simply `if entry in list_template: print item`

Comment: Change the inner loop to advance only after each entry found. For example, after entry1 found, print it and advance to entry2 (in template list)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `dict`:

```
>>> listlog
['entry1:abcde', 'entry2:abbds', 'entry1:eorieo', 'entry3:orieqor', 'entry2:iroewiow']
>>> list_template
['entry1', 'entry2', 'entry3']
>>> for x in listlog:
...     key, value = x.split(":")
...     if key not in my_dict and key in list_template:
...         my_dict[key] = value
... 
>>> my_dict
{'entry2': 'abbds', 'entry3': 'orieqor', 'entry1': 'abcde'}
```

Comment: removing entries from `list_template` as they are found would be more efficient that checking if they are already defined in the dictionary.

Comment: you should also use `break` once every element is found

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `list comprehension` something like this:

```
import re

listlog = ["entry1:abcde", "entry2:abbds", "entry1:eorieo", "entry3:orieqor", "entry2:iroewiow"]

print([item for item in listlog if re.search('entry', item)])
# ['entry1:abcde', 'entry2:abbds', 'entry1:eorieo', 'entry3:orieqor', 'entry2:iroewiow']
```

Than u can split 'em as u wish and create a dictonary if u want:

```
import re

listlog = ["entry1:abcde", "entry2:abbds", "entry1:eorieo", "entry3:orieqor", "entry2:iroewiow"]

mylist = [item for item in listlog if re.search('entry', item)]

def create_dict(string, dict_splitter=':'):
    _dict = {}

    temp = string.split(dict_splitter)
    key = temp[0]
    value = temp[1]
    _dict[key] = value

    return _dict


mydictionary = {}

for x in mylist:
    x = str(x)
    mydictionary.update(create_dict(x))


for k, v in mydictionary.items():
    print(k, v)
    # entry1 eorieo
    # entry2 iroewiow
    # entry3 orieqor
```

As you see this method need an update, cause we have changing the dictionary value. That's bad. Most better to update value for the same key. But it's much easier as u can think

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer : This answer could use someone's insight on performance. Sure, list/dict comprehensions and zip are *pythonic* but the following may very well be a poor use of those tools.

You could use `zip` :

```
>>> data = ["a:12", "b:32", "c:54"]
>>> ref = ['c', 'b']
>>> matches = zip(ref, [val for key,val in [item.split(':') for item in data] if key in ref])
>>> for k, v in matches:
>>>     print("{}:{}".format(k, v))
c:32
b:54
```

Here's another (worse? I'm not sure, performance-wise) way to get around this :

```
>>> data = ["a:12", "b:32", "c:54"]
>>> data_dict = {x:y for x,y in [item.split(':') for item in data]}
>>> ["{}:{}".format(key, val) for key,val in md.items() if key in ref]
['b:32', 'c:54']
```

Explanation :

1. Convert your initial list into a dict using a dict
2. For each pair of (key, val) found in the dict, join both in a string if the key is found in the 'ref' list